# Is it possible to add cases to a Select Case based on the number of entries in a table?

Tags: vba, excel, case-statement, select-case

I've been messing around with VBA in Excel a bit recently; and as a small project for myself, I'm trying to create a "draw names from a hat" sort of macro.

I began by generating a random number, and then choosing which entry from a Table (i.e. ListObject) would be selected using a case statement.  The problem with this is that it only works of the number of Table entries is always the same.

So my question (probably a ridiculous one) is: is it possible at all to generate a dynamic 'Select Case' block, where the number of cases on the block is based on the number of entries in the Table?

Thanks.

-Sean

Edit: To clarify: what I am trying to do, exactly, is this:

I generate a random number, i, from 1 to n=10*(number of Table entries).  After this, I want to display, in a cell, one of the table entries based on the random number.

Ideally, the code would work similarly to this:

```
if i = 1 to 10 then choose event 1
if i = 11 to 20 then choose event 2
if i = 21 to 30 then choose event 3
...
if i = (n-9) to n then choose event (n/10)
```

I hope this helps to clarify the goal of the code.

Comment: You might not even need a select case. What are you trying to do after you generate the random number and choose your entry? Display something? Run additional code? You should be able to do this just using and array, but I'm curious to know more of what you're doing.

Comment: @AlexD I've edited the question to provide some clarity, hopefully it helps you in understanding what I'm trying to do.  Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: I believe I know where you're getting at, but I'll comment here until I get a full understanding. I can show you how, if you can confirm this is what you're looking for. But basically generate an array from the table entries, generate a random number and then set like Cell(1, 4).Value = Array(random_number). Or MsgBox(Array(random_number)). Depending on how exactly you want it to play out.

Comment: @AlexD that is exactly what I am getting at, and yours is a much simpler and cleaner way to get the job done.  Also, I've never really done much of anything with arrays in VBA, so it should be a good experience!

Comment: I'll write something a bit closer up in VBA and post it for your reference.

Comment: What is the significance of `10`?

Comment: @user2140261 there is no real significance.  Based on the way that the `Rnd` variable works in VBA, generating a random number from `1 To (number of Table entries)` and then selecting a case based on a single number (instead of a range, like the code above shows) is exactly the same thing as what I've written above.  To be perfectly honest using the 10-number range was entirely arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our comments here is something you can use:

```
Sub random()
    Dim used_rows As Integer
    Dim random As Integer
    Dim cell_array() As Integer
    used_rows = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ReDim cell_array(used_rows)
    For i = 1 To used_rows
        cell_array(i - 1) = Cells(i, 1)
    Next
    random = Int(Rnd * (used_rows))
    MsgBox cell_array(random)
End Sub
```

You can go ahead and change MsgBox to whatever you like, or set like Cell(1,4).Value = cell_array(random), or however you'd like to proceed. It will be based off the number of rows used. Though depending on how you implement your spreadsheet the code might have to be changed a bit.

Here's the update code from the suggestions from the comments. Also remember to use Randomize() in your form initialization or WorkBook Open functions.

```
Sub random()
    Dim used_rows As Integer
    Dim random As Integer
    'Multiple ways to get the row count, this is just a simple one which will work for most implementations
    used_rows = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    random = Int(Rnd * (used_rows)) 
    'I use the variable only for the reason that you might want to reference it later
    MsgBox Cells(random, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help.  A quick question about the use of arrays: what is the purpose of the intial `Dim cell_array() As Integer` and then the `ReDim`?  Is that always necessary when using arrays?

Comment: The array and loop are pretty wasteful as they are not needed to get the same answer. You could just pass in a range then do `MsgBox Int(Rnd * Range.Rows.Count)`. Also you should use the `Randomize` function along with the `Rnd` function, as everytime you open the workbook `Rnd` will reset the seed to the same value and it will just repeat all the number, IT WILL NOT BE RANDOM. Using the `Randomize` function along with `Rnd` will give much better results as it uses the System TimeValue for the seed.

Comment: DetroitWilly For the original Dim call you can't pass it a variable to set the size, but ReDim I can pass it a variable for the proper size. It's not always necessary, if you know the size of your array you can just set it to taht originally.
@user2140261 Thank you very much! I'll update my code and edit in a new version.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that by "table" you mean "Table with a capital T", known in VBA as a `ListObject`:

```
Sub PickRandomTens()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
Dim ListRowsCount As Long
Dim RandomNumber As Long
Dim ListEvent As String
Dim Tens As Long

Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
ListRowsCount = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
RandomNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(10, ListRowsCount * 10)
ListEvent = lo.ListColumns("Data Column").DataBodyRange.Cells(Int(RandomNumber / 10))
MsgBox "Random number: " & RandomNumber & vbCrLf & _
       "Event: " & ListEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: I was referring to a ListObject.  I will provide an edit for future reference.  Out of curiosity, do you think that there is any advantage to using the `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween` over the VBA `Rnd` variable?  Also, what is `vbCrLf`?  You don't mention it anywhere else in the code.

Comment: I used `RandBetween` because I can remember the syntax :). `Rnd` might be better, I'm not sure. `VbCrLf` is just a linefeed, so that the message is on two rows.

Comment: Ah, that is a good reason.  And thanks for the info on vbCrLf.  I will have to commit that to memory!